# LD_PRELOAD for hooking open() only works on proc file system

Tags: system-calls, proc, ld-preload

I am trying to map all the files created and opened by my program. For that purpose I have implemented my own `open()` function, that writes the filepath parameter to an output file, and than calls the original `open()`. Using `LD_PRELOAD` I am successfully hooking proc file system `open()`, but not a direct `open()` in my code.

The following code is hooked by `LD_PRELOAD`:
`system("echo text > /user/prog");`

The following code is NOT hooked by `LD_PRELOAD`:
`open("/user/prog", O_RDWR, O_CREAT);`

the two code lines are located in the same file, right next to each other. 
What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Just guessing, but does your program set `LD_PRELOAD`? If so, it's likely too late for it to affect the program itself. You could either set it for the program in advance, or have it `exec()` itself with the new environment.

Comment: I'm running my program like this: 
`LD_PRELOAD=/myopen.so prog`. 
Is it not the correct way to do it?

Comment: also, I am connecting with ssh to my Linux pc through a windows pc, and then running the program, if it matters.

Comment: That seems right. If your program isn't statically linked, and it isn't in secure-execution mode (e.g. from being a set-uid binary), I'd expect that to work.

Comment: Are  your `myopen.so` library and your `prog` executable both built with the same word size?  (I.e. both 32-bit or both 64-bit.)

Comment: My prog is compiled and ran with an `edk tool`, which might be with a different word size than my pc. Will check, thanks.